# C preprocessor: building a path string

Tags: c, macros, include, c-preprocessor

Given a macro that has been defined previously:

```
#define FILENAME somefile.h
```

I want to concatenate this with another macro-string that defines the (relative) path of this file. My current approach is to do this like so:

```
#define DIRECTORY ../somedir/

#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define FILE2_(dir, file) STRINGIFY_(dir ## file)
#define FILE_(dir, file) FILE2_(dir, file)

#include FILE_(DIRECTORY, FILENAME)
```

This however results in an error (GCC4.9):

> error: pasting "/" and "file" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Removing the final forward slash from the `DIRECTORY` definition removes this error, but obviously does not yield the desired result. Similar errors appear when I try to smuggle the `/` in otherwise. For example:

```
#define FILE2_(dir, file) STRINGIFY_(dir ## / ## file)
```

does not work for the same reason.

I would like to know what is going wrong here and, obviously, how to circumvent this.

**EDIT**: Changed double underscores to singles on Columbo's advice. Apparently, identifiers containing double underscores are reserved to the implementation, regardless of where they appear (I was under the impression that this only held true for double underscores at the beginning of an ID).

Comment: First of all, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: The files in `#include` directives can't be macros, at least as far as I know. So what you are trying to achieve won't work.

Comment: @Oehm Then why does this even exist? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html

Comment: Well, seems that "as far as i know" wasn't far enough.

Comment: Haha fair enough. It seemed to me that if I could construct a macro that is expanded to "../somedir/somefile.h", it should work. Maybe @Columbo would like to elaborate on his comment?

Comment: @JorenHeit You're using reserved names. :o) I'm currently working on an answer to this question, seems interesting.

Comment: @Columbo I was under the impression that double underscores *in front of* the identifier were reserved... Not true?

Comment: @JorenHeit Any double underscore makes the name reserved.

Comment: Okay, will change to singles then.

Comment: @Columbo begin with double underscore.

Comment: **6.10.8 Predefined macro names 2** _Any other predefined macro names
shall begin with a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter or a second
underscore._

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  [global.names] *"Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
(1.1) — Each name that contains a double underscore __ [..] is reserved to the implementation for any use."* I wouldn't mess with that.

Comment: @Columbo It's also the same in C++. **16.8 Predefined macro names 4** _Any other predefined macro names shall begin
with a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter or a second underscore._

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't know how that is relevant. The above macros name might clash with a global identifier, an intrinsic or other stuff. *any use* means **any use**. You can't use such names in any context.

Comment: The name of the macro can be solved by the preprocessor.  `17.6.4.3.1 Macro names` , `17.6.4.3.2 Global names` Section is divided. it should not be confused.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `#define A__ 4 /* newline */ #include <iostream>`, where `<iostream>` declares a global identifier `int A__;`; it is allowed to. What now?

Comment: But it is certainly inferred that has not been such an implementation because it is not reserved as a macro name  .

Comment: i actually checked iostream implementation by GCC did not exist such a name. (Using begin with __)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 1. Please reply to me via <at>Columbo, otherwise I can't see when you do so. 2. Of course your implementations  <iostream> is not declaring A__, that was an example. The point is that you cannot use double underscores in any identifier you declare, because names with a double underscore are reserved for any use. And 'use' goes beyound macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cpp.include]/4:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# include` *pp-tokens new-line*
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The
>   preprocessing tokens after `include` in the directive are processed
>   just as in normal text (i.e., each identifier currently defined as a
>   macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing
>   tokens). If the directive resulting after all replacements does not
>   match one of the two previous forms, the behavior is
>   undefined.<sup>152</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>152</sup> **Note that adjacent string literals are not
>   concatenated into a single string literal (see the translation phases
>   in 2.2); thus, an expansion that results in two string literals is an
>   invalid directive.**

So though `#include MACRO` is valid, `MACRO` must directly expand to an otherwise valid argument to `#include`. The concatenation of string literals happens two translation phases after preprocessing.

Also, in the definition of the `##` operator, [cpp.concat]/3:

> For both object-like and function-like macro invocations, before the replacement list is reexamined for more
>   macro names to replace, each instance of a `##` preprocessing token in the replacement list (not from an
>   argument) is deleted and **the preceding preprocessing token is concatenated with the following preprocessing
>   token**.
>   [..] **If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.**

Hence the result of `A##B` must be **one** valid preprocessing token. / is an own preprocessing token, and so are the names of the directories and files.
You can't concatenate `"abc` and `/xyz"`, since `abc/` is not a valid preprocessing token - `"abc` is not one preprocessing token, but two, though `"abc"` is one.
On the other hand, if you concatenate `<abc/` and `xyz>`, then `/` and `xyz` are concatenated, examined, and we have a problem again.

Thus it appears to be impossible to concat the paths using `##`. Your approach looks quite impossible to me, too.

---

With GCC, this is fine though:

```
#define PATH <foo/bar/
#define FILE boo>

#define ARG PATH FILE
#include ARG
```

It [**works**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80add0c2eb7d784b) because GCCs preprocessor removes the white space (for some reason). Does not work on VC++ or Clang and isn't covered by standard anyway, so definitely not recommended.